# Заголовочные файлы проекта C++: ошибка "redefinition of `class ClassName'"

Tags: c++

Разбил файл на 3 файла, и не получается его скомпилировать. Полагаю, ошибка в неправильном подключении заголовочных файлов.

SomeClass.h

```
    #include "Update.h"
    #include <iostream.h>

    class SomeClass:public Updatable
    {
        int a;
        public:
        void start () 
        {
            std::cout<<"Start SomeClass\n";
        }
        void update ()
        {
            std::cout<<"SomeClass update: "<<a++<<'\n';
        }
        SomeClass ()
        {
            a=0;
        }
    };

    void AddSomeClass ()
    {
        Updatemodule.AddToList (new SomeClass ());
    }
```

Update.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

class Updatable
{
    friend class UpdateModule;
    virtual void start ()=0; 
    virtual void update ();  
};

class UpdateModule
{
    std::vector <Updatable*> script;
    public:
    void AddToList (Updatable*upd)
    {
        script.push_back (upd);
        upd->start ();
    }
    void Start ()
    {

    }
    void Update ()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<script.size ();i++)
                script [i]->update ();

            Sleep (50);
        }
    }
}Updatemodule;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Update.h"
#include "SomeClass.h"

void AddEvents ()
{
    AddSomeClass ();
}

int main()
{       
    AddEvents ();
    Updatemodule.Update ();
    return 0;
}
```

```
--------------------Configuration: mingw5 - CUI Debug, Builder Type: MinGW--------------------

Checking file dependency...
Compiling C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\main.cpp...
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:5: error: redefinition of `class Updatable'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:5: error: previous definition of `class Updatable'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:12: error: redefinition of `class UpdateModule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:12: error: previous definition of `class UpdateModule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: conflicting declaration 'int Updatemodule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: 'Updatemodule' has a previous declaration as `UpdateModule Updatemodule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of `int Updatemodule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: previous external decl of `UpdateModule Updatemodule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: declaration of `int Updatemodule'
[Error] C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\1\Update.h:34: error: conflicts with previous declaration `UpdateModule Updatemodule'
[Warning] C:\PROGRA~2\C-FREE~1\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.5\backward\backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

Complete Make main: 11 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Comment: Где текст ошибки?

Comment: А в чем ошибка?

Comment: Добавил текст ошибок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли защититься от повторного включения файла. Например, для *Update.h:*

```
#ifndef UPDATE_H
#define UPDATE_H

// Содержимое Update.h

#endif
```

Или, как вариант:

```
#pragma once

// Содержимое Update.h
```

Можно с двойной защитой:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef UPDATE_H
#define UPDATE_H

// Содержимое Update.h

#endif
```

Второй способ (только `#pragma once`) работает со всеми популярными компиляторами, но он не является частью стандарта.

Comment: [Error] C:\PROGRA~2\C-FREE~1\mingw\include\C__~1\348B92~1.5\ext\new_allocator.h:(.text$_ZN9UpdatableC2Ev[Updatable::Updatable()]+0x8): undefined reference to `vtable for Updatable'

Comment: Ну или `#pragma once`, т. к. у include guard'ы очевидно не абсолютно надёжны.

Comment: @VladD Ну, старый дедовский способ. Какие-то инструменты гуиды приписывают для уникальности...

Comment: Гуиды как бы тоже не гарантируют, от copy/paste ещё никто не защитился :-)

Comment: @Dmitry У вас отсутствует реализация `virtual void update ()` — нужно или сделать метод чисто виртуальным, или реализовать его (пусть и с путым телом).

Comment: Athari, огромное спасибо, заработало!

Comment: @VladD Дополнил ответ. Проверяйте. :)

Comment: Угу, так бронебойно. :)